# how to add badge to Appbar Actions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try to add badge for Appbar Actions, but there are errors about postion in differenct device. Can you help me?

```
actions: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 20,
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60,
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                      icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(right: 3, top: 3, child: MyBadge(10)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
    ]
```

ui in iphone

[image: ui in iphone]

ui in ipad

[image: ui in ipad]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Badges Package](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) and it will automatically make badge

```
import 'package:badges/badges.dart';
.
.
 Badge(
      badgeContent: Text('10'),
      child: Icon(Icons.email),
    )
```

Even you can use animations to make it cool :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package   [badges: ^2.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

```
    import 'package:badges/badges.dart';

     Badge(
          badgeContent: Text('3'),
          child: Icon(Icons.settings),
        )
```

**You can also add style tou the badge**

```
BadgeAnimationType.slide
```

*I just slightly edited your code*

```
actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 20,
              ),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                      right: 3,
                      top: 3,
                      child: Badge(
                        badgeContent: Text('3'),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.settings,
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
]
```